# How to show live video streaming in Asp.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

How to show live video streaming in Asp.Net Webforms?

I want to display live video stream in my web application. Where I am reading the live video stream from DVR box, I have achieved displaying live video stream in windows form application through picture box control as shown in below code.

```
[DllImport("HCNetSDK.dll")]
public static extern int NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30(int iUserID, ref NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, REALDATACALLBACK fRealDataCallBack_V30, IntPtr pUser, UInt32     bBlocked);

PreviewDemo.CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo1 = new PreviewDemo.CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO();

lpClientInfo.lChannel = 1;
lpClientInfo.hPlayWnd = PictureBox1.Handle;
lpClientInfo.lLinkMode = 0;
lpClientInfo.sMultiCastIP = null;

//Method to get video Stream
m_lRealHandle = PreviewDemo.CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30(f, ref lpClientInfo, null, pUser, 1); 

public struct NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO
{
public Int32 lChannel;
public Int32 lLinkMode;
public IntPtr hPlayWnd;
public string sMultiCastIP;
}
```

How do I show live video streaming in asp.net webform, please help me on how can I achieve the above in asp.net webforms?

Comment: Looking for same thing and still not able to get the answer! If you have came across any solution then please share it.

Comment: Did you get a solution?